# Optimization software for ARM Architecture

Tags: cplex, gurobi

Given that tomorrow Apple will likely announce the first ARM Macs ([per bloomberg](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2020-06-20/apple-to-sell-developers-on-building-new-apps-amid-pushback)), I was wondering what the current status of ARM support in optimization software. For instance, does anyone know if Gurobi or CPLEX plan on supporting ARM? Is there any current optimization solver that can be compiled for ARM?

Comment: The package coinor-cbc is contained in Ubuntu for ARM, so CBC should run on arm. According to [here](http://www.pokutta.com/blog/random/2019/09/29/scipberry.html), also SCIP should run on ARM. I would also expect that Gurobi and CPLEX will continue supporting Macs, but of course, I don't know.

Comment: Do not hold your breath for ARM support at Mac. In any case we at www.mosek.com  has an ARM build for Linux we let users try.

Comment: It seems ARM on MAC is coming end of 2021. A big question is how fast optimization software that is floating intensive will run on the ARM CPUs.

Comment: @ErlingMOSEK I second that, guarantying the numerics on a different architecture is a function of many things (including compilers), plus the added complexity of maintaining all current builds & integrations on multiple architectures, so unfortunately I don't see many of us investing resources to support that until there is sufficient market demand.

Comment: Gurobi latest release is now providing native support the M1. https://www.gurobi.com/news/gurobi-9-5-delivers-enterprise-features-and-even-better-performance/

Answer (score 4):

CPLEX does not provide ARM support yet but there is a request for enhancement at

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=126844

and you may vote for this

Comment: Does this voting for features also exist for Gurobi?